# Ads for android that can be filtered for children

Tags: android, admob, ads

I did add AdMob ads to my android application. But I couldnt manage to filter apps to be appropriate and interesting for kids! Ads that kids would click. As game apps.

Filtering ads to only include apps is a plus and too fancy that I will not ask for.

Does anyone had a similar experience and managed to achieve it?

Comment: I guess you tried to use admob filters.

Comment: yes. it only allow to block limited categories and the rest is alot and not categorised for kids or else.

Comment: I don't think you can do more in this case.